# Is there an equivalent to git gui for mercurial under ubuntu?

Tags: git, user-interface, ubuntu, mercurial

Is there an equivalent to git gui for mercurial under ubuntu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most commonly used Linux GUI for Hg is [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/). For a more simple view-only interface there is the [hgk extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgkExtension).

I think the former is more useful, but hgk more closely resembles git gui.

Comment: Thanks, hgk seems awfully like gitk, but tortoise hg provides a commit tool like git gui.

Comment: Use the command `hgtk` to invoke the GUI from the terminal. No need for that nasty nautilus stuff.

Comment: Right, I meant to say hgk resembles gitk. Not super familiar with the git GUI tools :)

Answer (score 4):

Kamil has your answer. Though you might also be interested in [the list of GUIs given in the Mercurial wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/OtherTools).

Answer (score 2):

`hgview` provided by "hgview" package.